# exec command not running java class for HIVE connection in PHP

Tags: java, php, hadoop

I am trying to execute java class using exec method of PHP, This java class is to download file from  HDFS using kerberose authentication. If I run separate java -jar it work fine. But the same if I call from PHP as below its giving some version error please help

```
exec("java -jar ./HDFSDownload.jar 'pl_data/20161130_IWORK_PL_PIT.txt' ", $output );
print_r($output);
```

Error in webpage as below :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: HDFSDownload : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449) at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Comment: if you were going for hardest thing to read ever, you succeeded. please make that bottom line readable

Comment: The title mentions "Hive" i.e. a database but the post is about HDFS i.e. a file system. Then you show an error message that is purely an internal Java issue, and has nothing to do with Hadoop. Wake up!

Comment: I solved this issue.. As error message states Java version was wrong .. means the compiled version and executing version were not matching.    Since I am calling java in PHP this question relates to PHP command and have JAVA class which have HIVE connection in it. Please wake up!! I hope its right forum ..